# Ember: search in a tree table

Tags: javascript, ember.js

We have a hierarchical model:

```
segments
  demographic
    age
    language
    location
  interest
    art
    charity
    entertainment
      books
      movies
      music
```

We put it in a table that has expandable rows:

```
▶ segments
```

When you click on the arrow next to `segments`, you'll see:

```
▼ segments
  ▶ demographic
  ▶ interest
```

then when you click the arrow next to `interest`, you'll see:

```
▼ segments
  ▶ demographic
  ▼ interest
      art
      charity
    ▶ entertainment
```

You get the idea.

**The trick is, children nodes that are invisible are not in the store yet (async).**
**Clicking an arrow fetches the children from the server.**

---

Now, the model is implemented this way in Ember Data:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('segment', {
    async: true
  }),
  children: DS.hasMany('segment', {
    async: true,
    inverse: 'parent'
  })
});
```

---

Now, we want to implement *search* functionality:

- user types something in search text input
- server returns search results
- we render it in the table

The problem here is that we want to show the whole path.

Let's say, we search for `o`, we'd like to see not only the results that contain the letter `o` but also all the parents:

```
▼ segments
  ▼ demographic
      location
  ▼ interest
    ▼ entertainment
        books
        movies
```

---

Problem:

Assume that we fetched all the items from above example.

If we want to render `interest`, its children list is *incomplete*.

It's missing `art` and `charity` which is fine for this view. But in the model, `children` thinks it's loaded but it's only partially loaded.

What should be an approach here?

- have "search mode" and when you abandon it, reload children
- have a separate field in the model for `searchChildren`?
- use a completely separate model for searching?
- are we doing this wrong?

Thanks for any hints!